# Flow property for semimartingale driven SDE at a stopping time

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $S$ be an $n$-dimensional semimartingale such that the SDE

$$dX_t = \sigma(X_t, t) \, dS_t$$

with $\sigma$ Lipschitz continuous admits a globally defined unique strong solution on $[0, T]$.

For $t \geq 0$, and $x \in \mathbb R$, we denote by $X^{x, t}$ the process with $X^{x, t}_s := x$ for all $s \leq t$, and thereafter following the dynamics of the above SDE.

Let $\tau$ be a stopping time with respect to the natural filtration of $S$.

I wish to prove the following flow property of the SDE:

> $X^{X^{x, 0}_\tau, \tau} = X^{x, 0}$ almost surely on $[\tau, T]$.

More precisely, can we show the following result?

For $\mathbb P$-almost every $\omega$, we have that for every $t \geq \tau(\omega)$,

$$X^{x, 0}_t (\omega) = X^{X^{x, 0}_{\tau(\omega)}, \tau(\omega)}_t (\omega).$$

I searched in standard references such as Protter and Ikeda-Watanabe but was not able to find much.